# How to make jquery background slideshow affect only parent div?

Tags: jquery, background, parent

I have been trying to figure this out all day, and keep on running in circles. I have two issues I was hoping to get help with. **First**: I have a jquery background slideshow displaying inside a div. The problem is that when the background fades out to introduce the new image, so does the children of the DIV the background was meant for, I dont want that. You can see it [at my website here](http://www.ind-mediagroup.com/branding/) How can I isolate the parent DIV so that the child doesnt fade out as well? Here is the code for the slideshow:

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">  
    $(document).ready(function(){    
        var imgArr = [ // relative paths of images  
            'http://www.ind-mediagroup.com/wp-content/themes/twentyeleven/indeximg/1.jpg',  
            'http://www.ind-mediagroup.com/wp-content/themes/twentyeleven/indeximg/2.jpg',  
            'http://www.ind-mediagroup.com/wp-content/themes/twentyeleven/indeximg/3.jpg',  
            'http://www.ind-mediagroup.com/wp-content/themes/twentyeleven/indeximg/4.jpg' 
        ];    

    var preloadArr = [];  
    var i;    

    /* preload images */ 

    for(i=0; i < imgArr.length; i++){  
        preloadArr[i] = new Image();  
        preloadArr[i].src = imgArr[i];  
    }    

    var currImg = 1;  
    var intID = setInterval(changeImg, 6000);    

    /* image rotator */ 

    function changeImg(){  
        $('#centerdiv').animate({opacity: 0}, 1000, function(){  
            $(this).css('background','url(' + 
                preloadArr[currImg++%preloadArr.length].src +') center fixed no-repeat');  
        }).animate({opacity: 1}, 1000);
        $('#centerdiv').css({'background-size': '100% 100%'}); }    
    }); 

</script>
```

Here is the CSS pertaining to the issue (I know much of it may be redundant):

```
 #centerdiv {
    width:100%;
    height: 642px;
    background-color: #333333;
    background-image:url('http://www.ind-mediagroup.com/wp-  content/themes/twentyeleven/indeximg/houston-night.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;/* i believe the next few lines are dealt with in the jquery code*/
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-position: center;
    background-attachment: fixed;

    top:0px;
    padding-top: 55px;
}

.contentdiv {
    width: 78%;
    height: 75%;
    margin: auto auto auto 140px; 
    background-image: url('http://www.ind-mediagroup.com/wp-   content/themes/twentyeleven/indeximg/whitetransbg.png');
    position: relative;
    z-index: 10;
}
```

Here is the HTML pertaining to the issue:

```
<div id="centerdiv">
    <div class="contentdiv">
        <div class="wrappercontent">
            <div id="contentname">
                <p class="contentTextHeader">+<?php the_title() ?></p>
            </div>

            <div id="content">

                <?php
                    if (have_posts()) :
                        while (have_posts()) :
                            the_post();
                            the_content();
                        endwhile;
                    endif;
                ?>

            </div>

            <div id="contentright">
                <?php echo apply_filters('the_content', get_post_meta($post->ID, 'page_image', true) ); ?>       
            </div>
        </div> 
    </div>
</div>
```

**Second** issue is this: I want the background images to fill 100% of the div space. I managed to get this to work in Chrome by adding:

```
$('#centerdiv').css({'background-size': '100% 100%'});
```

I am not a jquery expert, so i am by far no expert, and am not sure if the preceding code is even correct, but in other browsers, its giving me a weird effect. It will show the larger image, and immediately after show the image that is correctly sized. Using the existing jquery code, is there a way to do this?

I really appreciate any help. I am sooooo very close to where I want it to be.

Comment: Can you also show some HTML fragment reagrding your question? Please also format your code to be better readable.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I edited the post to add the pertinent HTML...hopefully that helps...I am not sure how you would like me to format the code?

Comment: You should do the animation of the background image on a div that doesn't have any child elements. As you already noticed, the children also fade out, but this is normal behaviour.

Comment: i will try that...thanks! How about my second issue re: the background size?

Comment: FYI, i did what was suggested, and it works...it actually helps the design overall, so i really appreciate the help!

Comment: Welcome. You may vote up my comment.

Answer (score 0):

`contentdiv` must be placed outside the `centrediv`. `contentdiv` must be absolutely positioned kind of overlaying. I used orbit slider for image sliding.

Sample html:

```
<style type="text/css">
    #centerdiv{
        border-radius: 3px;
    }
    #contentdiv{
        position: absolute;
        top: 20px;
        left:40px;
        z-index: 300;
    }
</style>

<body>

    <div id="centerdiv">
        <img src="http://www.lorempixum.com/898/270/animals" alt="" /> 
        <img src="http://www.lorempixum.com/898/270/city" alt="" /> 
        <img src="http://www.lorempixum.com/898/270/food" alt="" /> 
        <img src="http://www.lorempixum.com/898/270/sports" alt="" /> 
    </div>
    <div id="contentdiv">
            This is my text
    </div>
    <pre>Animals -> City -> Food -> Sports</pre>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(window).load(
            function(){
                $('#centerdiv').orbit({
            'timer': true,
            'advanceSpeed': 6000,
            'bullets' : false,
            'bulletThumbs': false, 
            });});
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks, I think I might end up using orbit...how would you have the second issue i have re: the background image sizing?